# Typescript/Lodash - Group data in series

Tags: typescript, lodash

I am trying to figure out how to group values in series.
For example, I would like to transform the data below

```
[
    {"book": "Typescript 1", "year": "2015", "units": 1000}, 
    {"book": "Javascript 1", "year": "2015", "units": 2000}, 
    {"book": "Typescript1", "year": "2016", "units": 6000}
]
```

**in**

```
[   
    {
         "book": "Typescript 1",
         "series": [
              {"year": "2015", "units": 1000},
              {"year": "2016", "units": 6000}
         ]
    },   
    {
         "book": "Javascript 1",
         "series": [
              {"year": "2015", "units": 2000}
         ]   
    } 
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by array and add field and sub array in main array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523003/group-by-array-and-add-field-and-sub-array-in-main-array)

Comment: I notice that the first book name has a space in it, and the last one does not. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read  ["Why using `_.chain` is a mistake."](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba) and why `flow()` is advised.

Here is a fewliner that approaches the problem from *functional programming* perspective:

```
import tap from "lodash/fp/tap";
import flow from "lodash/fp/flow";
import groupBy from "lodash/fp/groupBy";

const map = require('lodash/fp/map').convert({ 'cap': false });

const result = flow(
        groupBy('book'),
        map((series, book) => ({book, series: series.map(({units, year}) => 
        ({year, units}) )})),
        tap(console.log)
    )(input)
```

Where `input` is an array that you want to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a succinct way to do it with plain JavaScript using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const books = [
  {"book": "Typescript 1", "year": "2015", "units": 1000}, 
  {"book": "Javascript 1", "year": "2015", "units": 2000}, 
  {"book": "Typescript 1", "year": "2016", "units": 6000}
];

const merged = Object.values(books.reduce((acc, { book, year, units }) => {
  acc[book] = acc[book] || { book, series: [] };
  acc[book].series.push({ year, units });
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score -1):

I will provide an starting point approach without using typescript. If you want more help you should tell us which is your approach.

```
var original = [
    {"book": "Typescript 1", "year": "2015", "units": 1000}, 
    {"book": "Javascript 1", "year": "2015", "units": 2000}, 
    {"book": "Typescript1", "year": "2016", "units": 6000}
];

const mapBook = new Map();

original.forEach((value) => {
    const year = value['year'];
    const book = value['book'];
    const units = value['units'];

    if(!mapBook.has(book)) {
        const mapYear = new Map();
        mapYear.set(year, units);
        mapBook.set(book, mapYear);
    } else { 
        const mapYear = mapBook.get(book);
        if(mapYear.has(year)){
            //Decide what to do if it is reapeted
        } else {
            mapYear.set(year, units);
            mapBook.set(book, mapYear);
        }
    }
});
const mapBookIterator = mapBook.entries();
for(let [key, value] of mapBookIterator ){
    //iterate your entries and build your object
    console.log(key, value);
}
```