# Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested, grouping

I have this array of objects, that I need to modify to make it easier the rendering.

```
const items = [
  {
    tab: 'Results',
    section: '2017',
    title: 'Full year Results',
    description: 'Something here',
  },
    {
    tab: 'Results',
    section: '2017',
    title: 'Half year Results',
    description: 'Something here',
  },
    {
    tab: 'Reports',
    section: 'Marketing',
    title: 'First Report',
    description: 'Something here',
  },
  ...
];
```

and I'm trying to modify it, grouping them by specific keys. The idea is to have this output. As you can see the names of the keys could be different than the actual names in the items. I think that makes a bit different from previous posts.

```
const output = [
  {
    tab: 'Results',
    sections: [
      {
         section: '2017',
         items: [ { 'item that belongs here' }, { ... } ],
      },
  },
  {
    tab: 'Reports',
    sections: [
      {
         section: 'Marketing',
         items: [ { ... }, { ... } ],
      },
  },
...
]
```

I tried using `lodash.groupby`, but it doesn't do exactly what i'm looking for. 
Any idea about how to approach it?

Many thanks!!

Comment: which key you want to be grouped?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by array and add field and sub array in main array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523003/group-by-array-and-add-field-and-sub-array-in-main-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with a clever combinartion of `_.map` and `_.groupBy`.

```js
const items = [
  {
    tab: 'Results',
    section: '2017',
    title: 'Full year Results',
    description: 'Something here',
  },
    {
    tab: 'Results',
    section: '2017',
    title: 'Half year Results',
    description: 'Something here',
  },
    {
    tab: 'Reports',
    section: 'Marketing',
    title: 'First Report',
    description: 'Something here',
  }
];

function groupAndMap(items, itemKey, childKey, predic){
    return _.map(_.groupBy(items,itemKey), (obj,key) => ({
        [itemKey]: key,
        [childKey]: (predic && predic(obj)) || obj
    }));
}

var result = groupAndMap(items,"tab","sections", 
                   arr => groupAndMap(arr,"section", "items"));


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an object without additional libraries.

The object contains a property `_` which keeps the nested arrays of the given nested group.

```js
var items = [{ tab: 'Results', section: '2017', title: 'Full year Results', description: 'Something here' }, { tab: 'Results', section: '2017', title: 'Half year Results', description: 'Something here' }, { tab: 'Reports', section: 'Marketing', title: 'First Report', description: 'Something here' }],
    keys = { tab: 'sections', section: 'items' }, // or more if required
    result = [],
    temp = { _: result };

items.forEach(function (object) {
    Object.keys(keys).reduce(function (level, key) {
        if (!level[object[key]]) {
            level[object[key]] = { _: [] };
            level._.push({ [key]: object[key], [keys[key]]: level[object[key]]._ });
        }
        return level[object[key]];
    }, temp)._.push({ title: object.title, description: object.description });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The solution looks really neat, thanks! 
Also @Jamiec solution works perfect, now the only doubt would be which one is more efficient...

Comment: @JCGarcia I would bet on this one, more native than using lodash. @Nina, is a `Map` better than using a simple object `{}`? Very nice solution btw!!

Comment: @sjahan, the object is maybe faster with a for loop.

Comment: I would personally always defer to Nina's better knowledge ;) Except that this doesnt do the second level of aggregation on sections

Comment: @Jamiec, sorry, haven't seen the nested grouping.

Comment: @NinaScholz watchout, i think your new version does not match the expected result anymore! :/

Comment: @sjahan, and now?

Comment: @NinaScholz Perfect! :)