# Modifying an array of objects to group into a nested parent / child array of objects by keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently trying to modify an array of objects to break out into a nested array of objects based on grouping the value of a key.

This is an example of the initial data format:

```
[
    {key: "Toyota", color: "red", cost: 100 },
    {key: "Toyota", color: "green", cost: 200 },
    {key: "Chevrolet", color: "blue", cost: 300 },
    {key: "Honda", color: "yellow", cost: 400 },
    {key: "Datsun", color: "purple", cost: 500 }
]
```

This is the output I'm trying to put together:

```
[{
   key: "Toyota", 
   values:  [
    {color: "red", cost: 100 },
    {color: "green", cost: 200 }
  ]
 }, {
   key: "Chevrolet", 
   values:  [
    {color: "blue", cost: 300 }
  ]
 },{
   key: "Honda", 
   values:  [
    {color: "yellow", cost: 400 }
  ]
 },{
   key: "Datsun", 
   values:  [
    {color: "puruple", cost: 500 }
  ]
 }]
```

So far I've had some success with these solutions (mostly using the `_.map` + `_.groupBy` solution in lodash), which is helping to split the data into a parent -> child format. I'm currently still having some trouble with grouping based on values as well as keys.
[Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)

Current data format looks something like:

```
 [{
   key: "Toyota", 
   values:  [
    {color: "red", cost: 100 },
  ]
 },{
   key: "Toyota", 
   values:  [
    {color: "green", cost: 200 }
  ]
 }, {
   key: "Chevrolet", 
   values:  [
    {color: "blue", cost: 300 }
  ]
 },{
   key: "Honda", 
   values:  [
    {color: "yellow", cost: 400 }
  ]
 },{
   key: "Datsun", 
   values:  [
    {color: "puruple", cost: 500 }
  ]
 }]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You'll want to show the code that got you that far; otherwise, this is a duplicate of the question you posted. You'll need to explain what about the code you didn't understand too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) without additional libraries.

(This is my original answer of the referenced question with single nested rerquirement. The question has a nested approach with more then one level depth, which is here not given.)

```js
var items = [{ key: "Toyota", color: "red", cost: 100 }, { key: "Toyota", color: "green", cost: 200 }, { key: "Chevrolet", color: "blue", cost: 300 }, { key: "Honda", color: "yellow", cost: 400 }, { key: "Datsun", color: "purple", cost: 500 }],
    map = new Map,
    result;

items.forEach(({ key, color, cost }) => {
    map.has(key) || map.set(key, { key, values: [] });
    map.get(key).values.push({ color, cost });
});

result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```