# Finding pairs in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I basically have the following JavaScript object:

```
records: [
{
   id: 1,
   name: michael,
   guid: 12345
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: jason,
   guid: 12345
},
{
   id: 3,
   name: fox,
   guid: 54321
},
{
   id: 4,
   name: rachel,
   guid: 54321
}
];
```

What I wanna do is find the pairs with the same guid. I plan to create another object that contains both records. So it would look like the ff:

```
records: [
    {
       id: 1,
       name: michael,
       guid: 12345,
       id2: 2,
       name2: jason
    },
    {
       id: 3,
       name: fox,
       guid: 54321,
       id2: 4,
       name2: rachel
    }];
```

How do I do that in JavaScript? or is there some sort of function where I could combine them from the same object? so that I wouldn't need to create another. Thank you

Comment: That isn't valid JSON

Comment: Impossible because its not a JSON object.

Comment: What if you have more than two names? Impractical approach to managing/storing programmable data.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: It's a JS Object, or JavaScript Object. Anyway, take a look at the Array functions `filter()`, `map()` and `reduce()`. Like you said, you should only post here if all else fail[s].

Comment: `var JSObject = [
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "michael",
   "guid": 12345
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "jason",
   "guid": 12345
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "name": "fox",
   "guid": 54321
},
{
   "id": 4,
   "name": "rachel",
   "guid": 54321
}
]`

Comment: No you really want  that output? Because if you just want to group by `guid` [the answer is already out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)...

Comment: And a better approach would be to consolidate per guid:  `{
 "12345": [{ "id": 1, "name": "michael" },
           { "id": 2, "name": "jason"   }
 ],
  "54321":[{ "id": 3, "name": "fox"},
           { "id": 4, "name": "rachel" }]
}`

Answer (score 0):

You want to first address your syntax. strings must be quoted. you can't assign a variable with ':' must use '='. There are a bunch of ways you approach this, here are a couple. Next time it's best to post some code you've already attempted, shows your trying to learn and not just get an answer.

```
var records = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'michael',
    guid: 12345
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'jason',
    guid: 12345
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'fox',
    guid: 54321
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'rachel',
    guid: 54321
  }
];

// vanilla js
var groups = {};
records.forEach(function(obj) {
  if (!groups[obj.guid]) {
    groups[obj.guid] = [obj];
  } else {
    groups[obj.guid].push(obj);
  }
});

// lodash
var lo_groups = _.groupBy(records, 'guid');

console.log(groups, lo_groups);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you unique records

```js
var recrds = [
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "michael",
   "guid": 12345
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "jason",
   "guid": 12345
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "name": "fox",
   "guid": 54321
},
{
   "id": 4,
   "name": "rachel",
   "guid": 54321
}
];

function printRecords(){
  let unique = [...new Set(recrds.map(item => item.guid))];
  return unique;
}
```