# Hierarchical response with javascript looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have below  json.

```
[{ 
    "employeeId" : "10", 
    "ownerId" : "15", 
    "reports" : [
        {
            "employeeId" : "1", 
            "name" : "kotak", 
            "ownerId" : "6", 
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "4", 
            "name" : "blackbarry", 
            "ownerId" : "8", 
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "2", 
            "name" : "dell", 
            "ownerId" : "6", 
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "5", 
            "name" : "nokia", 
            "ownerId" : "8", 
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "6", 
            "name" : "sony", 
            "ownerId" : "10", 
        }, 
        {
            "employeeId" : "8", 
            "name" : "samsung", 
            "ownerId" : "10", 
        }
    ]
}]
```

This will be the Hierarchical scenario

```
      10     ->>> owner
      /\
     /  \
    8    6  ---->> 8 & 6 reports to owner 10
    /\    /\
   /  \  /  \
  4    5 2   1  ---->> 4 & 5 reports to owner 8 ...
```

I need to do some type of looping to get this type of result. There can be more nested level as you can see the last `reports` array is blank.

Suppose If have `12` as a `employeeId` then Hierarchical  will be

```
          12   
        /    \
       /      \
      10        8  
      /\         /\
     /  \       /  \
    7    6      5   4 
   /      \    /     \
  /        \  /       \
```

Expected result

```
[{
    "employeeId" : "10",
    "ownerId" : "15",
    "reports" : [
        {
            "employeeId" : "6",
            "name" : "sony",
            "ownerId" : "10",
            "reports" : [
                {
                        "employeeId" : "1",
                        "name" : "kotak",
                        "ownerId" : "6",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "employeeId" : "2",
                        "name" : "dell",
                        "ownerId" : "6",
                        "reports" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "employeeId" : "8",
            "name" : "samsung",
            "ownerId" : "10",
            "reports" : [
                {
                    "employeeId" : "5",
                    "name" : "nokia",
                    "ownerId" : "8",
                    "reports" : [ ]
                },
                {
                    "employeeId" : "4",
                    "name" : "blackbarry",
                    "ownerId" : "8",
                    "reports" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Please Help!!!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have tried to many thing but didn't able to  achieve the result please help. I could not able post more code due to some restriction `Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).` .. **Please help** I am  newbie here

Comment: You have to post the code you've tried if you want debugging help.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks buddy but the duplicate question is slightly different.