# Spread syntax for nested javascript object with dynamic properties for grouping

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

```
const data = [{year:2019,month:1,id:"xd1"},
 {year:2019,month:1,id:"xd2"},
 {year:2019,month:1,id:"xd4"},
 {year:2019,month:2,id:"xd1"},
 {year:2018,month:1,id:"rd3"},
 {year:2018,month:2,id:"rd6"},
 {year:2018,month:2,id:"rd7"}
]

const result = data.reduce((state,d)=>{
    return {
        ...state,
        [d.year]:{
            ...state[d.year],
            [d.month]:[
                ...state[d.year][d.month]
                ,d.id]
        }
    }
},{})

console.log(result);



const result = data.reduce((state,d)=>{
    return {
        ...state,
        [d.year]:{
            ...state[d.year],
            [d.month]:[].concat([state[d.year][d.month]],[d.id])
        }
    }
},{})
```

both return an Error `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`
How can I use the spread syntax to get a grouped result like this.

```
{'2019':{
   '1':["xd1","xd2","xd3"],
   '2':["xd1"]},
 '2018':{
   '1':["rd3"],
   '2':["rd6","rd7"]
 }

}
```

Please consider using reduce and spread syntax and not chaining other methods because the its actually part of a bigger construct and other things wont help.
Thx.
EDIT: like stated in the comments. I would explicitly like solve it inline with spread operator that returns new objects or arrays. No extra libraries like lodash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)

Comment: When the `state` is empty, there won't be a `state[d.year]` so `state[d.year][d.month]` will be the error you see.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think this is a duplicate question. The  object structure is slightly different and solutions contain lodash and not spread.

Comment: @Pointy yeah kind of know that is is the problem. But do not know how to fix it inline spread-style... this is basically the question I am asking. If you could provide a solution this would be great.

Comment: I am expecting that you can figure out the minor details needed to adapt the answer to your structure. There are several solutions there that do not use lodash. And why use the spread operator when you don't need to, or if it doesn't work?

Comment: Better focus on readability, rather than using spread in this case

Comment: because spread is hipster. Being unreadable is the new cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some `sh*t and sticks`:

```js
const data = [{year:2019,month:1,id:"xd1"},
 {year:2019,month:1,id:"xd2"},
 {year:2019,month:1,id:"xd4"},
 {year:2019,month:2,id:"xd1"},
 {year:2018,month:1,id:"rd3"},
 {year:2018,month:2,id:"rd6"},
 {year:2018,month:2,id:"rd7"}
]

const result = data.reduce((state, d) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        [d.year]: {
            ...state[d.year],
            [d.month]: [
                ...((state[d.year]||{})[d.month]||[]),
                d.id]
        }
    }
},{})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It's a shame that js allows syntax like that

Comment: @bambam, "it's both a gift and a curse".

Comment: :-) True. Here it's a curse

Comment: thx, upvote for answering the actual question. Next time I'll ask if spread is *useful*, *beautiful* or *hipster*, but for now just - thanks

Comment: @silverfighter, happy to help.