# Convert JSON format (Group by)

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON object like this:

```
[{
    "name" : "cat",
    "value" : 17,
    "group" : "animal",
},
 {
    "name" : "dog",
    "value" : 6,
    "group" : "animal",
},
 {
    "name" : "snak",
    "value" : 2,
    "group" : "animal",
},
{
    "name" : "tesla",
    "value" : 11,
    "group" : "car",
},
{
    "name" : "bmw",
    "value" : 23,
    "group" : "car",
}]
```

I want to convert this JSON to below format by JS:

```
[{
  "name":"animal",
  "children":[
     {"name":"cat", "value":17},
     {"name":"dog", "value":6},
     {"name":"snak", "value":2}
]},
{
  "name":"car",
  "children":[
     {"name":"bmw", "value":11},
     {"name":"tesla", "value":23}
]}]
```

I try to convert and filter by `Reduce` function but I couldn't convert to this format.

EDIT:

The code I tested was this.

```
let groupBy = function(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
    }, {});
};

let groubedByExchange=groupBy(JSON_data, 'group');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could build an array and search for the same group in the array.

```js
var array = [{ name: "cat", value: 17, group: "animal" }, { name: "dog", value: 6, group: "animal" }, { name: "snak", value: 2, group: "animal" }, { name: "tesla", value: 11, group: "car" }, { name: "bmw", value: 23, group: "car" }],
    result = array.reduce((r, { group: name, ...object }) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => o.name === name);
        if (!temp) r.push(temp = { name, children: [] });
        temp.children.push(object);
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution is to build an intermediate dictonary and then transform it to your output structure.

You can use `Array.reduce()`, `Object.entries()` and `Array.map()` to do it:

```js
const data = [
  { "name" : "cat", "value" : 17, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "dog", "value" : 6, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "snak", "value" : 2, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "tesla", "value" : 11, "group" : "car" },
  { "name" : "bmw", "value" : 23, "group" : "car" }
];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, { name, value, group }) => {
  acc[group] = (acc[group] || []);
  acc[group].push({ name, value });
  return acc;
}, {})).map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, children: value }));

console.log(result);
```

Using the spread operator makes it one line shorter and still readable:

```js
const data = [
  { "name" : "cat", "value" : 17, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "dog", "value" : 6, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "snak", "value" : 2, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "tesla", "value" : 11, "group" : "car" },
  { "name" : "bmw", "value" : 23, "group" : "car" }
];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, { name, value, group }) => {
  acc[group] = [...(acc[group] || []), { name, value }];
  return acc;
}, {})).map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, children: value }));

console.log(result);
```

And one liner shorter with the comma operator:

```js
const data = [
  { "name" : "cat", "value" : 17, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "dog", "value" : 6, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "snak", "value" : 2, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "tesla", "value" : 11, "group" : "car" },
  { "name" : "bmw", "value" : 23, "group" : "car" }
];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, { name, value, group }) =>
  (acc[group] = [...(acc[group] || []), { name, value }], acc)
, {})).map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, children: value }));

console.log(result);
```

The same can be done with `Object.assign()`:

```js
const data = [
  { "name" : "cat", "value" : 17, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "dog", "value" : 6, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "snak", "value" : 2, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "tesla", "value" : 11, "group" : "car" },
  { "name" : "bmw", "value" : 23, "group" : "car" }
];

const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, { name, value, group }) =>
  Object.assign(acc, { [group]: [...(acc[group] || []), { name, value }] })
, {})).map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, children: value }));

console.log(result);
```

And finally, a bit longer but with a reusable `groupBy` function:

```js
const data = [
  { "name" : "cat", "value" : 17, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "dog", "value" : 6, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "snak", "value" : 2, "group" : "animal" },
  { "name" : "tesla", "value" : 11, "group" : "car" },
  { "name" : "bmw", "value" : 23, "group" : "car" }
];

const groupBy = prop => data => {
  return data.reduce((dict, item) => {
    const { [prop]: _, ...rest } = item;
    dict[item[prop]] = [...(dict[item[prop]] || []), rest];
    return dict;
  }, {});
};

const result = Object.entries(groupBy('group')(data))
  .map(([key, value]) => ({ name: key, children: value }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice use of Object.entries. I also like the `acc[group] = (acc[group] || []);` to avoid the if statement. This should be the accepted answer imo.

Answer (score 4):

Using Array#from, Array#reduce, Array#concat, destructuring, spread syntax and Map.

1. reorganize your data structure by using  Map
2. restructuring your data using .map

```js
const data=[{"name":"cat","value":17,"group":"animal",},{"name":"dog","value":6,"group":"animal",},{"name":"snak","value":2,"group":"animal",},{"name":"tesla","value":11,"group":"car",},{"name":"bmw","value":23,"group":"car",}];

const res = Array.from(
  data.reduce((a,{group, ...rest})=>{
    return a.set(group, [rest].concat(a.get(group)||[]));
  }, new Map())
).map(([group, children])=>({group,children}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr = [{
    "name": "cat",
    "value": 17,
    "group": "animal",
  },
  {
    "name": "dog",
    "value": 6,
    "group": "animal",
  },
  {
    "name": "snak",
    "value": 2,
    "group": "animal",
  },
  {
    "name": "tesla",
    "value": 11,
    "group": "car",
  },
  {
    "name": "bmw",
    "value": 23,
    "group": "car",
  }
]

const newFormat = arr.reduce((pre, cur) => {
  const group = pre.find(grp => grp.name === cur.group)
  if (group) {
    group.children.push({
      name: cur.name,
      value: cur.value
    })
    return pre
  }

  const newGroup = {
    name: cur.group,
    children: [{
      name: cur.name,
      value: cur.value
    }]
  }
  pre.push(newGroup)
  return pre
}, [])

console.log(newFormat)
```

there you go.
first you try to find that group in new array, if it exists you add that child to it. if not, you create the group and children array and push it to the array

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. You can use lodash to achieve the same.

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "cat",
    "value": 17,
    "group": "animal",
  },
  {
    "name": "dog",
    "value": 6,
    "group": "animal",
  },
  {
    "name": "snak",
    "value": 2,
    "group": "animal",
  },
  {
    "name": "tesla",
    "value": 11,
    "group": "car",
  },
  {
    "name": "bmw",
    "value": 23,
    "group": "car",
  }
]

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('group')
  .map((group, name) =>
    ({
      name,
      children: _.map(group, ({
        name: name,
        value
      }) => ({
        name,
        value
      }))
    }))
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my ES6 solution, using map and reduce:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "cat",
    value: 17,
    group: "animal"
  },
  {
    name: "dog",
    value: 6,
    group: "animal"
  },
  {
    name: "snak",
    value: 2,
    group: "animal"
  },
  {
    name: "tesla",
    value: 11,
    group: "car"
  },
  {
    name: "bmw",
    value: 23,
    group: "car"
  }
];

const grouped = data.reduce((acc, currItem) => {
  const groupKey = currItem.group;
  if (!acc[groupKey]) {
    acc[groupKey] = [currItem];
  } else {
    acc[groupKey].push(currItem);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const res = Object.keys(grouped).map(key => ({
  name: key,
  children: grouped[key].map(groupItem => ({
    name: groupItem.name,
    value: groupItem.value
  }))
}));

console.log(res);
```

Check the console output to see the intermediate results.

I think some of the other answers use an unnecessary find() (which is O(n)) while you can just test if a current group key is already in there in O(1).

I'm storing the grouped results in a intermediate variable `grouped` for clarity, but it can all be inlined.

Answer (score 1):

```
const transform = things =>
  things.reduce((acc, { name, value, group }) => {
    const existingGroup = acc.find(g => g.name === group) || {};
    return [
      ...acc.filter(g => g.name !== group),
      {
        ...existingGroup,
        name: group,
        children: [...(existingGroup.children || []), { name, value }],
      },
    ];
  }, []);
```