# Javascript:JSON: group by an element

Tags: javascript

I have an array of JSON objects and am trying to group it by an element. I followed the sample code from
[Convert JSON format (Group by)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756136/convert-json-format-group-by)

```js
const groupBy = prop => data => {
    return data.reduce((dict, item) => {
        const { [prop]: _, ...rest } = item;
        dict[item[prop]] = [...(dict[item[prop]] || []), rest];
        return dict;
    }, {});
};

var data = [
    { PlazaID: 1, LaneID: 2, CamID: 3, CamDesc: 'Camera - 3' },
    { PlazaID: 1, LaneID: 2, CamID: 4, CamDesc: 'Camera - 4' },
    { PlazaID: 1, LaneID: 3, CamID: 3, CamDesc: 'Camera - 3' },
    { PlazaID: 1, LaneID: 3, CamID: 4, CamDesc: 'Camera - 4' },
];
```

I am trying to morph the above json into

```js
[
    'LaneID': 2, Cameras: [{'CamID': 3, 'CamDesc': 'Camera - 3'}, {'CamID': 4, 'CamDesc': 'Camera - 4'}],
    'LaneID': 3, Cameras: [{'CamID': 3, 'CamDesc': 'Camera - 3'}, {'CamID': 4, 'CamDesc': 'Camera - 4'}]
]
```

Example invocation:

```js
groupBy('LaneID')(data);
```

I am able to get the data grouped by LaneID, but I can't seem to get the Cameras grouped by.

Comment: Make sure to correctly format your JavaScript code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    { PlazaID: 1, LaneID: 2, CamID: 3, CamDesc: 'Camera - 3' },
    { PlazaID: 1, LaneID: 2, CamID: 4, CamDesc: 'Camera - 4' },
    { PlazaID: 1, LaneID: 3, CamID: 3, CamDesc: 'Camera - 3' },
    { PlazaID: 1, LaneID: 3, CamID: 4, CamDesc: 'Camera - 4' },
];

console.log(Object.values(data.reduce((a, { LaneID, PlazaID, ...o }) => 
  ((a[LaneID] ??= { LaneID, Cameras: [] }).Cameras.push(o), a), {})));
```

Comment: Make sure to correctly format your JavaScript code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way that could be understod very easy

```js
const groupBy = (data, column,child, onItem) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let x of data) {
       let b = x[column];
       let a = result.find(f=> f[column] === b);
       if (!a){
          a = {};
          a[column] = b;
          a[child] = [onItem(x)];
          result.push(a)        
       }else {
        a[child].push(onItem(x));
       }
  }
  return result
}

var data = [{
    'PlazaID': 1,
    'LaneID': 2,
    'CamID': 3,
    'CamDesc': 'Camera - 3'
  },
  {
    'PlazaID': 1,
    'LaneID': 2,
    'CamID': 4,
    'CamDesc': 'Camera - 4'
  },
  {
    'PlazaID': 1,
    'LaneID': 3,
    'CamID': 3,
    'CamDesc': 'Camera - 3'
  },
  {
    'PlazaID': 1,
    'LaneID': 3,
    'CamID': 4,
    'CamDesc': 'Camera - 4'
  }
];
const result = groupBy(data, "LaneID", "Cameras", (x)=> {
return {CamID: x.CamID,CamDesc: x.CamDesc }
})
console.log(result)
```