# Angular: How to use a groupBy Pipe in array

Tags: angular, pipe

```js
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';

/*
 * Group an array by a property (key)
 * Usage:
 *  value | groupBy : 'field'
 */

@Pipe({
  name: 'groupBy'
})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array < any > , field: string): Array < any > {
    // prevents the application from breaking if the array of objects doesn't exist yet
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }
    const groupedObj = value.reduce((previousVal, currentVal) => {
      if (!previousVal[currentVal[field]]) {
        previousVal[currentVal[field]] = [currentVal];
      } else {
        previousVal[currentVal[field]].push(currentVal);
      }
      return previousVal;
    }, {});
    // this will return an array of objects, each object containing a group of objects
    return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({
      key,
      value: groupedObj[key]
    }));
  }

}
```

I have implemented a custom groupBy pipe but it only works for a simple object string for instance it works when i pass something like this:

```
console.log(new GroupByPipe().transform(this.selectedServices, 'name'));
```

But i want to pass something more complex like this:

```
console.log(new GroupByPipe().transform(this.selectedServices,'paymentCycle.name'));
```

How can I make this pipe to accept a more complex groupBy such as this:

```
console.log(new GroupByPipe().transform(this.selectedServices, 'paymentCycle.name'));
```

Comment: any reason you revert the edit to make your post more complicated to understand?

Comment: Please [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names) and try to tweak it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to not implement the groupBy by yourself. Use lodash groupBy instead, it is capable of what you are searching for.

```
    const data = [
      { foo: { name: "A", id: "1" } },
      { foo: { name: "B", id: "1" } },
      { foo: { name: "A", id: "2" }}
    ];

    console.log(_.groupBy(data, 'foo.name')); // import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

(see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy)

Results in

```
{A: Array(2), B: Array(1)}
A: Array(2)
0: {foo: {…}}
1: {foo: {…}}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
B: Array(1)
0: {foo: {…}}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```