# group JSON in Javascript called using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to group my JSON object that I get when calling Ajax so I later implement it in my dependable dropdown list. I tried to group the values by CI, but all it did is split each character of all values :/ I tried **_.groupBy**, **for loops** ,but nothings seems to work .
The call is now just to test if I would be able to split the files as I want, to work on it later :

```
 $('#my_id').on('change', '#CISelect', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"{{url_for('CIType')}}",
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                var result = {}, 
                i = 0;
                $(data).each(function(key,item){
                    dataValue = item[i].CI;
                    if(!result[dataValue]){
                        result[dataValue] = [];
                        i++;
                    }
                    result[dataValue].push(item[i].CI);
                    i++;
                });
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
```

my JSON looks like this :

```
[{"CI":"GDV","Type":"Backup","TypeValue":20613},
{"CI":"GDV","Type":"Carepack","TypeValue":20642},
{"CI":"UNV","Type":"Digitalkamera","TypeValue":335}, 
{"CI":"UNV","Type":"Dockingstation","TypeValue":250},
{"CI":"PRT","Type":"Fax","TypeValue":325}, 
{"CI":"MOB","Type":"GSM Gateway","TypeValue":20648}]
```

what I want is this :

```
    {GDV : [{"Type":"Backup","TypeValue":20613},
            {"Type":"Carepack","TypeValue":20642}],
     UNV : [{"Type":"Digitalkamera","TypeValue":335}, 
            {"Type":"Dockingstation","TypeValue":250}],
     PRT : [{"Type":"Fax","TypeValue":325}}, 
     MOB : {{"Type":"GSM Gateway","TypeValue":20648}]}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I think your code needs few minor changes and it should work. Inside the first if condition push the complete item and outside the if condition as well. Check for each documentation it should have internal iterator so to get rid of explicit declaration of i variable.

Comment: @KrishnaSingh can you please explain me what should be fixed ? Thanks

Comment: JSON is a text format. Once you get the data back from `$.ajax`, it's just an array of objects. This may help you find the answer when searching.

Comment: Is your initial JSON is always grouped on `CI` key ?

Comment: @MisterJojo the initial is just each row values...it is not grouped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried to implement it to my code, but again it gives me back each character separated ....as all other I tried if they worked

Comment: Please [edit] your question with how you used the answers to the proposed duplicate question to try and solve the problem. It may be you're implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: The errors you seem to be getting (via comments on answers etc) suggest you haven't set a proper contentType serverside for this request. Either do so, and/or set the dataType property.

Comment: thank you all for help...but my idiot head wasn't thinking anymore... I forgot to add **JSON.parse** and that is why it was editing like a string :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution...  ( more simple... )

```js
let data =
  [ { CI: 'GDV', Type: 'Backup',         TypeValue: 20613 } 
  , { CI: 'PRT', Type: 'Fax',            TypeValue: 325   } 
  , { CI: 'GDV', Type: 'Carepack',       TypeValue: 20642 } 
  , { CI: 'UNV', Type: 'Digitalkamera',  TypeValue: 335   } 
  , { CI: 'UNV', Type: 'Dockingstation', TypeValue: 250   } 
  , { CI: 'MOB', Type: 'GSM Gateway',    TypeValue: 20648 } 
  ] 

result = data.reduce((acc,elm)=>{
  if ( acc[elm.CI] ) acc[elm.CI].push( { Type:elm.Type, TypeValue:elm.TypeValue } )
  else               acc[elm.CI] = [{ Type:elm.Type, TypeValue:elm.TypeValue }]
  return acc
},{})

console.log( result )
```

so your code should be :

```
$('#my_id').on('change', '#CISelect', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"{{url_for('CIType')}}",
    success:function(data){
      result = JSON.parse(data).reduce((acc,elm)=>{
        if ( acc[elm.CI] ) acc[elm.CI].push( { Type:elm.Type, TypeValue:elm.TypeValue } )
        else               acc[elm.CI] = [{ Type:elm.Type, TypeValue:elm.TypeValue }]
        return acc
      },{})
      console.log(result);
    }
  })
...
```

Comment: I tried it also, but it gives me back an error : **data.reduce is not a function**

Comment: First time I tested with **data.reduce**

Comment: @AmilaBečirović : also try `let result = JSON.parse( data ).reduce((acc,elm)=>{ ...`

Comment: Thanks , I totally forgot to use **JSON.parse** -.-  can't believe I forgot it :/ thanks for your help this works great

Answer (score -1):

```js
const raw = [
  { CI: "GDV", Type: "Backup", TypeValue: 20613 },
  { CI: "GDV", Type: "Carepack", TypeValue: 20642 },
  { CI: "UNV", Type: "Digitalkamera", TypeValue: 335 },
  { CI: "UNV", Type: "Dockingstation", TypeValue: 250 },
  { CI: "PRT", Type: "Fax", TypeValue: 325 },
  { CI: "MOB", Type: "GSM Gateway", TypeValue: 20648 }
];

// Distinc CI values
const dist_CI = [... new Set(raw.map(r => r.CI))];

const result = {};
for (let ci of dist_CI) {
  result[ci] = raw
    .filter(r => r.CI === ci)
    .map(r => {
      return {
        Type: r.Type,
        TypeValue: r.TypeValue
      };
    });
};
```

Result:

```js
{
   "GDV":[
      {
         "Type":"Backup",
         "TypeValue":20613
      },
      {
         "Type":"Carepack",
         "TypeValue":20642
      }
   ],
   "UNV":[
      {
         "Type":"Digitalkamera",
         "TypeValue":335
      },
      {
         "Type":"Dockingstation",
         "TypeValue":250
      }
   ],
   "PRT":[
      {
         "Type":"Fax",
         "TypeValue":325
      }
   ],
   "MOB":[
      {
         "Type":"GSM Gateway",
         "TypeValue":20648
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but I keep getting an error : raw.map is not a function

Comment: What's your browser?

Comment: Well, that can't be right. If you copy paste my code in chrome, it works. Are you trying to paste it in your ajax success function? If yes, then replace 'raw' with 'data', and it should work (as long as the schema is the one you described)

Comment: there is a difference between my JSON an yours, at mine **CI** is shown like this **"CI"** and yours **CI** and I did changed the raw with data

Comment: That shouldn't matter, it's just a display difference.

Comment: your is Real JSON syntax, his is one javascript object syntax

Answer (score -1):

You need to make minor adjustment

each iterator needs to be updated

```
$('#my_id').on('change', '#CISelect', function(){
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"{{url_for('CIType')}}",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var result = {}, 
        $.each(data,function(key,item){
            let dataValue = item["CI"]
            if(!result[dataValue]){
                result[dataValue] = [];
                result[dataValue].push({Type:item["Type"], TypeValue:item["TypeValue"]}); 
            }else{
            result[dataValue].push({Type:item["Type"], TypeValue:item["TypeValue"]}); 
            }
        });
        console.log(result);
    }
})
```

Comment: first solution gives me back an error : **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:**

Comment: try to use var for declaration for the dataValue