# Group JSON array by key value

Tags: javascript, json

Please help to combine object keys values from json arrays by key.

```js
    const input=[{
   "Date":"04/10/2019",
   "Time":"15:35",
   "Title":"Flight -\u00a0Group C",
   "Description":"Arrival 19:40"
},
{
   "Date":"04/10/2019",
   "Time":"Evening",
   "Title":"Welcome drinks",
   "Description":"In the bar at\u00a0"
},
{
   "Date":"05/10/2019",
   "Time":"Morning",
   "Title":"Breakfast",
   "Description":"At leisure"
},
{
   "Date":"05/10/2019",
   "Time":"10:00",
   "Title":"Something Else",
   "Description":"At leisure"
}];

console.log(
  Object.values(input.reduce((a, { Date }) => {
    if (!a[Date]) a[Date] = { Date, activities: [] };
    a[Date].activities.push();
    return a;
  }, {}))
);
```

I need a combined object keys values in javascript in the following way:

```js
[
   {
      "date":"04/10/2019",
      "activities":[
         {
            "Time":"15:35",
            "Title":"Flight -\u00a0Group C",
            "Description":"Arrival 19:40"
         },
         {
            "Time":"Evening",
            "Title":"Welcome drinks",
            "Description":"In the bar at\u00a0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "date":"05/10/2019",
      "activities":[
         {
            "Time":"Morning",
            "Title":"Breakfast",
            "Description":"At leisure"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I am trying to get the result with my code but 'activities' are null... 
I would highly appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Technical but important note: by definition, JSON is pure string data. You can't "do" anything with it until you `JSON.parse()` it, the result of which is _no longer_ JSON but is normal JS code (arrays, objects, etc). So if you're asking about grouping/sorting/etc, you're not asking about JSON. You're just trying to reorganise data inside plain JS data structures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using parameter destructuring you could use `...` rest param to get other properties after you take out the date.

```js
const input=[{"Date":"04/10/2019","Time":"15:35","Title":"Flight - Group C","Description":"Arrival 19:40"},{"Date":"04/10/2019","Time":"Evening","Title":"Welcome drinks","Description":"In the bar at "},{"Date":"05/10/2019","Time":"Morning","Title":"Breakfast","Description":"At leisure"},{"Date":"05/10/2019","Time":"10:00","Title":"Something Else","Description":"At leisure"}]

const object = input.reduce((r, { Date: date, ...rest}) => {
  if(!r[date]) r[date] = {date, activities: [rest]}
  else r[date].activities.push(rest)
  return r
}, {})

const result = Object.values(object)
console.log(result)
```