# How can I push to a subarray by grouping messages it in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm not very sure how I should name this question but I'll try to explain my problem. At the moment I've an array in PHP with some entries.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sender_id] => 0
            [message] => Test
            [created_at] => 2020-03-12 16:26:23
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sender_id] => 0
            [message] => Hello
            [created_at] => 2020-03-12 13:47:47
        )
)
```

What I needed was a way to group each entry by the created_at date so that my result looked like this:

```
Array
(
    [2020-03-12] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [sender_id] => 0
                    [message] => Test
                    [created_at] => 2020-03-12 16:26:23
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [sender_id] => 0
                    [message] => Hello
                    [created_at] => 2020-03-12 13:47:47
                )
        )

)
```

To reach this I've done this in PHP:

```
$grouped = [];

foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
    $created_at_date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $message->created_at ) );
    $grouped[ $created_at_date ][] = $message;
}
```

But now I'v got an issue so I decided to do this task in JS. So first I've encoded the array in PHP and set it to a variable inside a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
    let messages = <?= ! empty( $messages ) ? json_encode( $messages ) : '[]' ?>;
</script>
```

Now I've got a lot of messages but they are not grouped yet. Because I need to respect the timezone, I can only group them in JS where I know the clients timezone. I've already done the thing with the timezone but now I can't get the messages grouped like in PHP. This is what I've tried:

```js
let messages = [ {
 sender_id: "0",
 message: "Test",
 created_at: "Thu Mar 12 2020 17:26:23 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)"
}, {
 sender_id: "0",
 message: "Hallo",
 created_at: "Thu Mar 12 2020 17:26:23 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)"
} ];

let groupedMessages = [];

jQuery( messages ).each( function ( index, message ) {
 let createdAtDate = new Date( message["created_at"] ).toLocaleDateString( navigator.language, {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric"
 } );
  
 groupedMessages[createdAtDate][] = message;
} );

console.log( groupedMessages );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names

Comment: @Barmar This confuses me. I don't understand the logic :/

Comment: JavaScript doesn't use assignment to `[]` to push onto an array, that's only in PHP. JS uses the `.push()` method.[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're missing is :

```
jQuery( messages ).each( function ( index, message ) {
    let createdAtDate = new Date( message["created_at"] ).toLocaleDateString( navigator.language, {
        day: "2-digit",
        month: "2-digit",
        year: "numeric"
    } );

    if(typeof groupedMessages[createdAtDate] === 'undefined'){
        groupedMessages[createdAtDate] = [];
    }

    groupedMessages[createdAtDate].push(message);
} );
```

Comment: Perfect! It was so simple... But I'm good in PHP and not JS yet so thanks for your help!