# How to map a object into a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Having a problem with two arrays of objects and I want to concat data of them related to their id's.

I have two arrays of objects like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    default: false,
    id: 1,
    value: true,
    idModule: 1
  },
  {
    default: false,
    id: 2,
    value: true,
    idModule: 1
  },
  {
    default: false,
    id: 3,
    value: true,
    idModule: 2
  },
  {
    default: false,
    id: 4,
    value: true,
    idModule: 2
  }
];


const modulData = [
  {
    name: 'Administration',
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Benutzerverwaltung',
    id: 2,
  }
];
```

Now I want to combine these two related with their `idModule == id`
to create a new array of objects like this for example:

```js
const result = [
  {
    name: 'Administration',
    id: 1,
    modul: [
      {      
        default: false,
        id: 1,
        value: true,
        idModule: 1
      },
      {
        default: false,
        id: 2,
        value: true,
        idModule: 1
      },    
    ],

  },
  {
    name: 'Benutzerverwaltung',
    id: 2,
    modul: [
      {      
        default: false,
        id: 3,
        value: false,
        idModule: 2
      },
      {
        default: false,
        id: 4,
        value: false,
        idModule: 2
      },    
    ],
  }
];
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names for how to group the array by module ID

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simple by using `map` and `filter`:

```
let result = modulData.map(x => {
  x.modul = data.filter(d => d.idModule === x.id);
  return x;
});
```

Full code:

```js
const data = [{
    default: false,
    id: 1,
    value: true,
    idModule: 1
  },
  {
    default: false,
    id: 2,
    value: true,
    idModule: 1
  },
  {
    default: false,
    id: 3,
    value: true,
    idModule: 2
  },
  {
    default: false,
    id: 4,
    value: true,
    idModule: 2
  }
];


const modulData = [{
    name: 'Administration',
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Benutzerverwaltung',
    id: 2,
  }
];

let result = modulData.map(x => {
  x.modul = data.filter(d => d.idModule === x.id);
  return x;
});
console.log(result);
```