# ES6 - Create new array from an array based on key name using javascript es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Wanted to create a new array from an existing array (products) based on key (placement) value using ES6 syntax. The products can be many

Input array:

```
var products= [{
  "sku": "A00001",
  "price": 750,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_1"
},
{
  "sku": "A00002",
  "price": 750,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_1"
},
{
  "sku": "B04501",
  "price": 212,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_2"
},
{
  "sku": "A00451",
  "price": 110,
  "isNew": true,
  "isPurchasable": false,
  "placement": "item_page_2"
},
{
  "sku": "CA00013",
  "price": 350,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_1"
},
{
  "sku": "A045322",
  "price": 219,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_3"
},
{
  "sku": "A045323",
  "price": 33,
  "isNew": true,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_3"
},
{
  "sku": "D048823",
  "price": 426,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_1"
},
{
  "sku": "C055441",
  "price": 1310,
  "isNew": true,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_4"
}];
```

desire output:

```
{
  "placements":
    [
      {
        "placementName": "item_page_1",
        "items": [
            {
              "sku": "A00001",
              "price": 750,
              "isNew": false,
              "isPurchasable": true,
              "placement": "item_page_1"
            },
            {
              "sku": "A00002",
              "price": 750,
              "isNew": false,
              "isPurchasable": true,
              "placement": "item_page_1"
            },
            {
              "sku": "CA00013",
              "price": 350,
              "isNew": false,
              "isPurchasable": true,
              "placement": "item_page_1"
            },
            {
              "sku": "D048823",
              "price": 426,
              "isNew": false,
              "isPurchasable": true,
              "placement": "item_page_1"
            },
        ]
      },
      {
        "placementName": "item_page_2",
        "items":[
        {
            "sku": "B04501",
            "price": 212,
            "isNew": false,
            "isPurchasable": true,
            "placement": "item_page_2"
          },
          {
            "sku": "A00451",
            "price": 110,
            "isNew": true,
            "isPurchasable": false,
            "placement": "item_page_2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "placementName": "item_page_3",
        "items":[
          {
            "sku": "A045322",
            "price": 219,
            "isNew": false,
            "isPurchasable": true,
            "placement": "item_page_3"
          },
          {
            "sku": "A045323",
            "price": 33,
            "isNew": true,
            "isPurchasable": true,
            "placement": "item_page_3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "placementName": "item_page_4",
        "items":[
            {
              "sku": "C055441",
              "price": 1310,
              "isNew": true,
              "isPurchasable": true,
              "placement": "item_page_4"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an object with aggregate values for each key based on `placement`. Then get the `Object.values`

```js
const convert = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(({ placement, ...item }) => {
    if (!res[placement]) {
      res[placement] = { placementName: placement, items: [] };
    }
    res[placement].items.push({ placement, ...item });
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

var products = [
  {
    sku: "A00001",
    price: 750,
    isNew: false,
    isPurchasable: true,
    placement: "item_page_1",
  },
  {
    sku: "A00002",
    price: 750,
    isNew: false,
    isPurchasable: true,
    placement: "item_page_1",
  },
  {
    sku: "B04501",
    price: 212,
    isNew: false,
    isPurchasable: true,
    placement: "item_page_2",
  },
  {
    sku: "A00451",
    price: 110,
    isNew: true,
    isPurchasable: false,
    placement: "item_page_2",
  },
  {
    sku: "CA00013",
    price: 350,
    isNew: false,
    isPurchasable: true,
    placement: "item_page_1",
  },
  {
    sku: "A045322",
    price: 219,
    isNew: false,
    isPurchasable: true,
    placement: "item_page_3",
  },
  {
    sku: "A045323",
    price: 33,
    isNew: true,
    isPurchasable: true,
    placement: "item_page_3",
  },
  {
    sku: "D048823",
    price: 426,
    isNew: false,
    isPurchasable: true,
    placement: "item_page_1",
  },
  {
    sku: "C055441",
    price: 1310,
    isNew: true,
    isPurchasable: true,
    placement: "item_page_4",
  },
];

const output = { placements: convert(products) };
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could group products by `placement` and then manipulate the result by combining the use of `Object.entries` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)) and `map`

```js
var products = [
  { sku: "A00001", price: 750, isNew: false, isPurchasable: true, placement: "item_page_1" },
  { sku: "A00002", price: 750, isNew: false, isPurchasable: true, placement: "item_page_1" },
  { sku: "B04501", price: 212, isNew: false, isPurchasable: true, placement: "item_page_2" },
  { sku: "A00451", price: 110, isNew: true, isPurchasable: false, placement: "item_page_2" },
  { sku: "CA00013", price: 350, isNew: false, isPurchasable: true, placement: "item_page_1" },
  { sku: "A045322", price: 219, isNew: false, isPurchasable: true, placement: "item_page_3" },
  { sku: "A045323", price: 33, isNew: true, isPurchasable: true, placement: "item_page_3" },
  { sku: "D048823", price: 426, isNew: false, isPurchasable: true, placement: "item_page_1" },
  { sku: "C055441", price: 1310, isNew: true, isPurchasable: true, placement: "item_page_4" },
]

const groups = products.reduce((acc, product) => {
  if (acc[product.placement]) {
    acc[product.placement].push(product)
  } else {
    acc[product.placement] = [product]
  }
  return acc
}, {})

const res = {
  placements: Object.entries(groups).map(([key, value]) => ({
    placementName: key,
    items: value,
  })),
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Object.entries is not supported by IE.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the products with forEach. Look for every object if there is in the index-array an entry property placement. If not so, create this entry and add to the result-array a new placement-object with properties placement and for items an empty array. Otherwise just take with the index in the result the corresponding placement. In both cases add to the items-array the object.

```js
function transfer(array) {
    let result= {placements: []};
    let placements = [];
    
    array.forEach(obj => {
        let index = placements.indexOf(obj.placement);
        let placement;
        if (index==-1) {
            placement = {placementName: obj.placement, items: []};
            result.placements.push(placement);
            placements.push(obj.placement);
        } else {
            placement = result.placements[index];
        }
        placement.items.push(obj);
    });
    return result;
}

var products= [{
  "sku": "A00001",
  "price": 750,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_1"
},
{
  "sku": "A00002",
  "price": 750,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_1"
},
{
  "sku": "B04501",
  "price": 212,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_2"
},
{
  "sku": "A00451",
  "price": 110,
  "isNew": true,
  "isPurchasable": false,
  "placement": "item_page_2"
},
{
  "sku": "CA00013",
  "price": 350,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_1"
},
{
  "sku": "A045322",
  "price": 219,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_3"
},
{
  "sku": "A045323",
  "price": 33,
  "isNew": true,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_3"
},
{
  "sku": "D048823",
  "price": 426,
  "isNew": false,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_1"
},
{
  "sku": "C055441",
  "price": 1310,
  "isNew": true,
  "isPurchasable": true,
  "placement": "item_page_4"
}];

console.log(transfer(products));
```

Comment: should be products.forEach(obj => { or array.forEach(obj => { ??