# How to modify JSON response array to add new keys in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, collections, hashmap

I have a NodeJS function which is returning the following JSON array. It has all errors of type `1`:

```
const data1 =
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 9
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 1B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 2
  },
....
]
```

I have another JSON array for all errors of type `2`:

```
const data2 = 
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
    "Error": "wrong data for 2A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 8
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 2B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 3
  },
....
]
```

I have another JSON array for all errors of type `3`:

```
const data3 = 
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
    "Error": "wrong data for 3A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 1
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 3C",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 5
  },
....
]
```

I want to combine the 3 JSON arrays `data1`, `data2`, `data3` and the final JSON object should look as below:

```
{
  "details1": {
   "9": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A"
   },
      "2": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 1B"
   }
},
  "details2": {
   "8": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 2A"
   },
      "3": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 2B"
   }
},
  "details3": {
   "1": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 3A"
   },
      "5": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 3B"
   }
}
}
```

Please note that I want to add 3 new keys - `details1`, `details2` and `details3` - in the final response.
I also want to take out the `SERVER_COUNT` value and make it as a key.

I have added the following code but not sure to update it so as to get the final desired json

```
let finalData = Object.assign({}, ...data1.map(({
  SERVER_COUNT,
  ...rest
}) => ({
  [SERVER_COUNT]: rest
})));
```

Note: There are only 3 main keys and those are hard-coded `details1` , `details2`, `details13`

Comment: expected output is invalid

Comment: Also, this is not JSON, these are arrays with objects in them.

Comment: The desired result should be an object, not an array.

Comment: No you haven't. It still has `[]` around it when it should be `{}`

Comment: sorry. it is added now.

Comment: Where do the keys `details1`, `details2`, etc. come from? They don't appear anywhere in the original data.

Comment: there are only 3 such keys and those are hard-coded `details1` , `details2`, `details13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the array elements, turning each of them into an object property using the `SERVER_COUNT` property as the key.

```js
function dataToDetails (data) {
  let result = {};
  data.forEach(({ErrorType, Error, SERVER_COUNT}) => result[SERVER_COUNT] = {ErrorType, Error});
  return result;
}

const data1 =
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 9
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 1B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 2
  },

];

const data2 = 
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
    "Error": "wrong data for 2A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 8
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 2B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 3
  },

];

const data3 = 
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
    "Error": "wrong data for 3A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 1
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 3C",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 5
  },

];


let finalData = {
  details1: dataToDetails(data1),
  details2: dataToDetails(data2),
  details3: dataToDetails(data3)
};

console.log(finalData);
```

Comment: I have a situation where SERVER_COUNT has the same value and in such a situation it is not displaying all ErrorType values

Comment: `const data1 =
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 9
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 1B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 9
  },

];`

Comment: Object keys have to be unique. What are you expecting the result to be in that case?

Comment: `{
  "details1": {
   "9": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A"
   },
      "9": {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 1B"
   }
},
...`

Comment: It sounds like you need to revise your design to allow the value of the key to be an array of objects rather than a single object.

Comment: There can be more than 1 errortype which have the same count. And I want to display all of them as well.

Comment: I know what you want, but you can't do it like that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names for how to group objects with the same property value.

Comment: can you please change your answer accordingly? I can't change the structure of `data1` `data2` `data3`. It has to remain the same

Comment: My answer matches the structure of `finalResult` that you have in the question. If you want something different, update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your data arrays into one array called `all_data`, which you can then use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on to form an array of `[detailsN, object]` entries. Here `detailsN` represents your key for your outer object and the object represents the object for each detail key. Once you have mapped your all_data to entries, you can use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert it into an object.

The object component for the entires can be formed by mapping the data from each data array into `[SERVER_COUNT, obj]` entries, which you can then called Object.fromEntries() to convert the array of mapped entries into an object.

```js
const data1 = [ { "ErrorType": "Error-1A", "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A", "SERVER_COUNT": 9 }, { "ErrorType": "Error-1B", "Error": "password incorrect for 1B", "SERVER_COUNT": 2 }, ];
const data2 = [ { "ErrorType": "Error-2A", "Error": "wrong data for 2A", "SERVER_COUNT": 8 }, { "ErrorType": "Error-2B", "Error": "password incorrect for 2B", "SERVER_COUNT": 3 }, ];
const data3 = [ { "ErrorType": "Error-3A", "Error": "wrong data for 3A", "SERVER_COUNT": 1 }, { "ErrorType": "Error-3B", "Error": "password incorrect for 3C", "SERVER_COUNT": 5 }, ];

const keys = ["details1", "details2", "details3"];
const all_data = [data1, data2, data3];
const res = Object.fromEntries(all_data.map((data, i) => [
  keys[i], 
  Object.fromEntries(data.map(({SERVER_COUNT, ...r}) => [SERVER_COUNT, r]))
]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

JS pseudokode:.

1. Parse all joson to objects
2. Object.assigne or {...obj1, ...objt2};
3. transform object to json

```js
const data1 =
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
    "Error": "wrong ip address for 1A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 9
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 1B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 2
  }
]

const data2 = 
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
    "Error": "wrong data for 2A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 8
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 2B",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 3
  }
]

const data3 = 
[
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
    "Error": "wrong data for 3A",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 1
  },
  {
    "ErrorType": "Error-3B",
    "Error": "password incorrect for 3C",
    "SERVER_COUNT": 5
  }
]

console.log([data1, data2, data3].reduce((acc, cur, i) => Object.assign(acc, {["detailist" + i]: {...cur}}), {}))
```

[JS BIN](https://jsbin.com/xoserinumu/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: You have lots of typos

Comment: Where does this add the keys like `details:`, `details2:`, etc?

Comment: [Object.assigne](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: How would that do it? The key doesn't appear in `cur` anywhere.

Comment: if you know how works reduce, and how works Object assign then is obviously. you can reaplce this method in reduce by  (acc, cur) => ({...acc, ...cur})... this just combine objects.

Comment: I know how reduce and Object.assign works. `Object.assign()` can't create a property name that doesn't exist in the source or destination objects.

Comment: You only seem to be doing one of the `dataX`, not combining them all into `finalData`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an object structure like myObj={} you can add keys or properties like:

```
myObj.myKeyOrProperty = 'The data here';

// or

myObj.['myKeyOrProperty'] = 'The data here';
```

you need to serialize or deserialize to or from JSON to do that in request / response.

If you have a JSON response like an array of objects use:

```
array.push(myAwesomeObj-A);
array.push(myAwesomeObj-B);
array.push(myAwesomeObj-C);
etc...
```

When you have the desired data structure emit the response as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
{
"myDataKey": ---your data must be here in a JSON string format---
}
```