# I have an array of object in Javascript that I need to merge them based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays

The input array is

```js
[{
  "title": "book1",
  isInEnglish: true
}, {
  "title": "book1",
  isInFrench: true
}, {
  "title": "book2",
  isInEnglish: true
}, {
  "title": "book2",
  isInItalian: true
}, {
  "title": "book1",
  isInItalian: true
}, {
  "title": "book3",
  isInFrench: true
}]
```

The output should be

```js
[{
  "title": "book1",
  isInEnglish: true,
  isInFrench: true,
  isInItalian: true
}, {
  "title": "book2",
  isInEnglish: true,
  isInItalian: true
}, {
  "title": "book3": isInFrench: true
}]
```

Also, the edge case is if there is only one element in the array, it should return the input array, if there are two elements with same title value, it should merge, otherwise, just return the array.

Really appreciate any inputs provided to solve this.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names

Comment: It looks like people have not really read your question :) Try `theObjYouWant = [... new Set(os.map(o=>o.title))].map(t=> os.filter(o=>o.title === t).reduce((prev, curr) => ({...prev, ...curr}), {}))` where `os` is your so-called *input array*. Anyway, to complete @mplungjan's comment, see also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).