# Reducing an array of todos into an object of three objects by status

Tags: javascript

I have an array, and I'm trying to end up with an object containing three objects, `todo`, `completed` and `deleted`.

```
   const todos = [{
       id: 'a',
       name: 'Buy dog',
       action: 'a',
       status: 'deleted',
     },
     {
       id: 'b',
       name: 'Buy food',
       tooltip: null,
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'c',
       name: 'Heal dog',
       tooltip: null,
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'd',
       name: 'Todo this',
       action: 'd',
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'e',
       name: 'Todo that',
       action: 'e',
       status: 'todo',
     },
   ];

todos.reduce((acc, todo) => {
  console.log(acc);
  return {
    ...acc,
    [todo.status]: { ...acc[todo.status], ...todo }
  };
}, {});
```

The problem I'm having is that I only ever get the most recent 'completed' item. Can anyone help to point out where I'm going wrong?

Result wanted is:

```
{
  "deleted": [
    {
      "id": "a",
      "name": "Buy dog",
      "action": "a",
      "status": "deleted"
    }
  ],
  "completed": [
    {
      "id": "b",
      "name": "Buy food",
      "tooltip": null,
      "status": "completed"
    },
    {
      "id": "c",
      "name": "Heal dog",
      "tooltip": null,
      "status": "completed"
    },
    {
      "id": "d",
      "name": "Todo this",
      "action": "d",
      "status": "completed"
    }
  ],
  "todo": [
    {
      "id": "e",
      "name": "Todo that",
      "action": "e",
      "status": "todo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add exact wanted result?

Comment: So 1 object with 3 properties, each having an array as their respective value? `{todo: [], completed: [], deleted: []}`

Comment: it's not clear what you want - but it sounds likely maybe you want an object with an *array* for each of the 3 `completed` etc keys?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)

Comment: @nickzoum, sorry! Added desired result to question.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but you need to set the revised object to a new variable. Also, you probably want to aggregate arrays since there are multiple 'completed'. This first creates the base object and then populates it using `reduce()` for both actions

```
let keys=todos.reduce((b,a) => ({...b, [a.status]:[]}),{}), 
    revised = todos.reduce((b, todo) => {
    b[todo.status].push(todo);
     return b;
    }, keys);
```

```js
const todos = [{
       id: 'a',
       name: 'Buy dog',
       action: 'a',
       status: 'deleted',
     },
     {
       id: 'b',
       name: 'Buy food',
       tooltip: null,
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'c',
       name: 'Heal dog',
       tooltip: null,
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'd',
       name: 'Todo this',
       action: 'd',
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'e',
       name: 'Todo that',
       action: 'e',
       status: 'todo',
     },
   ];

let keys=todos.reduce((b,a) => ({...b, [a.status]:[]}),{}), 
revised = todos.reduce((b, todo) => {
b[todo.status].push(todo);
 return b;
}, keys);

  console.log(revised);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 const todos = [{id: 'a',name: 'Buy dog',action: 'a',status: 'deleted'},{id: 'b',name: 'Buy food',tooltip: null,status: 'completed'},{id: 'c',name: 'Heal dog',tooltip: null,status: 'completed'},{id: 'd',name: 'Todo this',action: 'd',status: 'completed'},{id: 'e',name: 'Todo that',action: 'e',status: 'todo'}];

const result = todos.reduce((acc, todo) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [todo.status]: acc[todo.status]
     ? [...acc[todo.status], { ...acc[todo.status], ...todo }] 
     : [todo]
  };
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Not sure if this result is what you are looking for. Basically in the end we will have an object with status as key, and the value will be an array that act as a grouping

Answer (score 0):

```
function getByValue(arr, value) {
    var result  = arr.filter(function(o){return o.status == value;} );
    return result? result[0] : null; // or undefined
}

todo_obj = getByValue(arr, 'todo')
deleted_obj = getByValue(arr, 'deleted')
completed_obj = getByValue(arr, 'completed')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, you just need to use the reduce function as an output - it doesn't mutate `todos` it returns a new value.

```js
const todos = [{id: 'a',name: 'Buy dog',action: 'a',status: 'deleted',},{id: 'b',name: 'Buy food',tooltip: null,status: 'completed',},{id: 'c',name: 'Heal dog',tooltip: null,status: 'completed',},{id: 'd',name: 'Todo this',action: 'd',status: 'completed',},{id: 'e',name: 'Todo that',action: 'e',status: 'todo',},];

const out = todos.reduce((acc, todo) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [todo.status]: { ...acc[todo.status], ...todo }
  };
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%} /* make preview prettier */
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been very clear in your question, I assume you want an output that looks like `{todo: [], completed: [], deleted: []}`.

In that case here is a simple solution.

```js
var todos = [{
    id: 'a',
    name: 'Buy dog',
    action: 'a',
    status: 'deleted',
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    name: 'Buy food',
    tooltip: null,
    status: 'completed',
  },
  {
    id: 'c',
    name: 'Heal dog',
    tooltip: null,
    status: 'completed',
  },
  {
    id: 'd',
    name: 'Todo this',
    action: 'd',
    status: 'completed',
  },
  {
    id: 'e',
    name: 'Todo that',
    action: 'e',
    status: 'todo',
  },
];

var result = todos.reduce(function(result, item) {
  var statusList = result[item.status];
  if (!statusList) {
    statusList = [];
    result[item.status] = statusList;
  }
  statusList.push(item);
 // or use this to create a deep copy
 // statusList.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)));
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `status` by destructing the `todo` and recalling (spreading) the previous value or using a new array with the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`). If your version of JS doesn't support that operator, you can fall back to using a [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) (`||`).

```js
const todos = [
  { id: 'a' , name: 'Buy dog'   , action: 'a'   , status: 'deleted'   },
  { id: 'b' , name: 'Buy food'  , tooltip: null , status: 'completed' },
  { id: 'c' , name: 'Heal dog'  , tooltip: null , status: 'completed' },
  { id: 'd' , name: 'Todo this' , action: 'd'   , status: 'completed' },
  { id: 'e' , name: 'Todo that' , action: 'e'   , status: 'todo'      }
];

const grouped = todos.reduce((acc, { status, ...rest }) => ({
  ...acc,
  [status]: [...(acc[status] ?? []), { ...rest, status }]
}), {});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting the most recent completed element from the original array because each object in your result is an object, not an array... It might be easier to start with a simple forEach instead of the reduce to see if that gets you what you need:

```js
   const todos = [{
       id: 'a',
       name: 'Buy dog',
       action: 'a',
       status: 'deleted',
     },
     {
       id: 'b',
       name: 'Buy food',
       tooltip: null,
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'c',
       name: 'Heal dog',
       tooltip: null,
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'd',
       name: 'Todo this',
       action: 'd',
       status: 'completed',
     },
     {
       id: 'e',
       name: 'Todo that',
       action: 'e',
       status: 'todo',
     },
   ];
let res = {}
todos.forEach(todo => {
  res[todo.status]=res[todo.status]||[]
  res[todo.status].push(todo)
})
console.log(res)
```