# Segregate array of object by id, then find sum of all amount fields and push all string elements to array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object and have to segregate based on id, then sum up all amount fields, push all string to an array and keep date fields empty.

I have tried to segregate the data but failed to find the sum of amount fields and other data.

```js
givenData = [
    { id: 'ABC001', code: 'AL', accountNo: '57808', debtDate: '2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 20000, totalPaid: 100, principalDue: 5000, principalPaid: 20, interestDue: 1000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 5000, penaltyPaid: 150 },
    { id: 'ABC001', code: 'AL', accountNo: '57808', debtDate: '2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 30000, totalPaid: 200, principalDue: 4000, principalPaid: 30, interestDue: 5000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 5000, penaltyPaid: 250 },
    { id: 'ABC001', code: 'HL', accountNo: '95783', debtDate: '2022-02-22T03:56:19.517Z', debtAmt: 2000, totalPaid: 300, principalDue: '', principalPaid: 50, interestDue: '', interestPaid: 10, penaltyDue: 4000, penaltyPaid: '' },
    { id: 'ABC001', code: 'HL', accountNo: '60092', debtDate: '2022-02-25T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 3000, totalPaid: 400, principalDue: 3000, principalPaid: 80, interestDue: 9000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 3000, penaltyPaid: 200 },

    { id: 'DEF123', code: 'HL', accountNo: '480001', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 2000, totalPaid: '', principalDue: 2000, principalPaid: 10, interestDue: 1000, interestPaid: 50, penaltyDue: 2000, penaltyPaid: 100 },
    { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480002', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 3000, totalPaid: '', principalDue: 500, principalPaid: 20, interestDue: 500, interestPaid: 100, penaltyDue: 1000, penaltyPaid: 150 },
    { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480003', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 4000, totalPaid: 100, principalDue: 100, principalPaid: 30, interestDue: 200, interestPaid: 200, penaltyDue: 500, penaltyPaid: 250 },
    { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480004', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 5000, totalPaid: 200, principalDue: '', principalPaid: 40, interestDue: 300, interestPaid: 300, penaltyDue: '', penaltyPaid: 300 },
    { id: 'DEF123', code: 'AL', accountNo: '480005', debtDate: '2022-03-04T10:52:18.161Z', debtAmt: 6000, totalPaid: 500, principalDue: 50, principalPaid: 60, interestDue: 400, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 100, penaltyPaid: 500 },

    { id: 'XYZ001', code: 'PL', accountNo: '878210', debtDate: '2021-09-21T11:38:53.733Z', debtAmt: 500, totalPaid: 600, principalDue: 800, principalPaid: 200, interestDue: 900, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 200, penaltyPaid: 100 },
    { id: 'XYZ001', code: 'DL', accountNo: '878211', debtDate: '2021-09-21T11:38:53.733Z', debtAmt: 700, totalPaid: 900, principalDue: 700, principalPaid: 100, interestDue: 300, interestPaid: '', penaltyDue: '', penaltyPaid: '' },
]

expectedResult = [
    {
        id: 'ABC001', code: ['AL', 'HL'], accountNo: ['57808', '95783', '60092'], debtAmt: 55000, totalPaid: 1000, principalDue: 12000, principalPaid: 180, interestDue: 15000, interestPaid: 70, penaltyDue: 17000, penaltyPaid: 500,
        subRows: [
            { id: 'ABC001', code: 'AL', accountNo: '57808', debtDate: '2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 20000, totalPaid: 100, principalDue: 5000, principalPaid: 20, interestDue: 1000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 5000, penaltyPaid: 150 },
            { id: 'ABC001', code: 'AL', accountNo: '57808', debtDate: '2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 30000, totalPaid: 200, principalDue: 4000, principalPaid: 30, interestDue: 5000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 5000, penaltyPaid: 250 },
            { id: 'ABC001', code: 'HL', accountNo: '95783', debtDate: '2022-02-22T03:56:19.517Z', debtAmt: 2000, totalPaid: 300, principalDue: '', principalPaid: 50, interestDue: '', interestPaid: 10, penaltyDue: 4000, penaltyPaid: '' },
            { id: 'ABC001', code: 'HL', accountNo: '60092', debtDate: '2022-02-25T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 3000, totalPaid: 400, principalDue: 3000, principalPaid: 80, interestDue: 9000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 3000, penaltyPaid: 200 }
        ]
    },

    {
        id: 'DEF123', code: ['HL', 'DL', 'AL'], accountNo: ['480001', '480002', '480003', '480004', '480005'], debtAmt: 20000, totalPaid: 800, principalDue: 2650, principalPaid: 160, interestDue: 2400, interestPaid: 1150, penaltyDue: 3600, penaltyPaid: 1300,
        subRows: [
            { id: 'DEF123', code: 'HL', accountNo: '480001', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 2000, totalPaid: '', principalDue: 2000, principalPaid: 10, interestDue: 1000, interestPaid: 50, penaltyDue: 2000, penaltyPaid: 100 },
            { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480002', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 3000, totalPaid: '', principalDue: 500, principalPaid: 20, interestDue: 500, interestPaid: 100, penaltyDue: 1000, penaltyPaid: 150 },
            { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480003', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 4000, totalPaid: 100, principalDue: 100, principalPaid: 30, interestDue: 200, interestPaid: 200, penaltyDue: 500, penaltyPaid: 250 },
            { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480004', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 5000, totalPaid: 200, principalDue: '', principalPaid: 40, interestDue: 300, interestPaid: 300, penaltyDue: '', penaltyPaid: 300 },
            { id: 'DEF123', code: 'AL', accountNo: '480005', debtDate: '2022-03-04T10:52:18.161Z', debtAmt: 6000, totalPaid: 500, principalDue: 50, principalPaid: 60, interestDue: 400, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 100, penaltyPaid: 500 }
        ]
    },

    {
        id: 'XYZ001', code: ['PL', 'DL'], accountNo: ['878210', '878211'], debtAmt: 1200, totalPaid: 1500, principalDue: 1500, principalPaid: 300, interestDue: 1200, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 200, penaltyPaid: 100,
        subRows: [
            { id: 'XYZ001', code: 'PL', accountNo: '878210', debtDate: '2021-09-21T11:38:53.733Z', debtAmt: 500, totalPaid: 600, principalDue: 800, principalPaid: 200, interestDue: 900, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 200, penaltyPaid: 100 },
            { id: 'XYZ001', code: 'DL', accountNo: '878211', debtDate: '2021-09-21T11:38:53.733Z', debtAmt: 700, totalPaid: 900, principalDue: 700, principalPaid: 100, interestDue: 300, interestPaid: '', penaltyDue: '', penaltyPaid: '' },
        ]
    },
]

const res = Object.values(givenData.reduce((acc, { id, code, accountNo, debtDate, debtAmt, totalPaid, principalDue, principalPaid, interestDue, interestPaid, penaltyDue, penaltyPaid }) => {
    acc[id] = acc[id] || { id, debtAmt, totalPaid, principalDue, principalPaid, interestDue, interestPaid, penaltyDue, penaltyPaid, subRows: [] };
    acc[id].subRows.push({ id, code, accountNo, debtDate, debtAmt, totalPaid, principalDue, principalPaid, interestDue, interestPaid, penaltyDue, penaltyPaid });
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: why is 60092 not in first accountNo expected result

Comment: its a mistake. sorry ill update

Comment: why is `debtdate`  `''` in some

Comment: date field should be kept empty in main primary object, if key debtdate is removed in primary object also no issues

Comment: in last element date is there

Comment: pls dont consider date fileds

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array of object nesting some of the keys with specific names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425797/group-array-of-object-nesting-some-of-the-keys-with-specific-names)

Comment: no.. suming of amount fields not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did in the most generic way with checking if the numeric fields contain `''`

If want can destructure in a way that the numeric fields are a seperate object using rest
`const { id, code, accountNo, debtDate, ...rest } = curr;`
and in the reduce

```js
Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    acc[id][k] = acc[id][k] || 0
    if (v!=='')acc[id][k]+=v
  })
```

```js
let givenData = [{ id: 'ABC001', code: 'AL', accountNo: '57808', debtDate: '2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 20000, totalPaid: 100, principalDue: 5000, principalPaid: 20, interestDue: 1000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 5000, penaltyPaid: 150 },{ id: 'ABC001', code: 'AL', accountNo: '57808', debtDate: '2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 30000, totalPaid: 200, principalDue: 4000, principalPaid: 30, interestDue: 5000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 5000, penaltyPaid: 250 },{ id: 'ABC001', code: 'HL', accountNo: '95783', debtDate: '2022-02-22T03:56:19.517Z', debtAmt: 2000, totalPaid: 300, principalDue: '', principalPaid: 50, interestDue: '', interestPaid: 10, penaltyDue: 4000, penaltyPaid: '' },{ id: 'ABC001', code: 'HL', accountNo: '60092', debtDate: '2022-02-25T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 3000, totalPaid: 400, principalDue: 3000, principalPaid: 80, interestDue: 9000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 3000, penaltyPaid: 200 },{ id: 'DEF123', code: 'HL', accountNo: '480001', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 2000, totalPaid: '', principalDue: 2000, principalPaid: 10, interestDue: 1000, interestPaid: 50, penaltyDue: 2000, penaltyPaid: 100 },{ id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480002', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 3000, totalPaid: '', principalDue: 500, principalPaid: 20, interestDue: 500, interestPaid: 100, penaltyDue: 1000, penaltyPaid: 150 },{ id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480003', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 4000, totalPaid: 100, principalDue: 100, principalPaid: 30, interestDue: 200, interestPaid: 200, penaltyDue: 500, penaltyPaid: 250 },{ id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480004', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 5000, totalPaid: 200, principalDue: '', principalPaid: 40, interestDue: 300, interestPaid: 300, penaltyDue: '', penaltyPaid: 300 },{ id: 'DEF123', code: 'AL', accountNo: '480005', debtDate: '2022-03-04T10:52:18.161Z', debtAmt: 6000, totalPaid: 500, principalDue: 50, principalPaid: 60, interestDue: 400, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 100, penaltyPaid: 500 },{ id: 'XYZ001', code: 'PL', accountNo: '878210', debtDate: '2021-09-21T11:38:53.733Z', debtAmt: 500, totalPaid: 600, principalDue: 800, principalPaid: 200, interestDue: 900, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 200, penaltyPaid: 100 },{ id: 'XYZ001', code: 'DL', accountNo: '878211', debtDate: '2021-09-21T11:38:53.733Z', debtAmt: 700, totalPaid: 900, principalDue: 700, principalPaid: 100, interestDue: 300, interestPaid: '', penaltyDue: '', penaltyPaid: '' },]


const res = Object.values(givenData.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    const { id, code, accountNo, debtDate, ...rest } = curr;
    acc[id] = acc[id] || { id, subRows: [], code: [], accountNo: [] };
  acc[id].accountNo.indexOf(accountNo) === -1 && acc[id].accountNo.push(accountNo)
  acc[id].code.indexOf(code) === -1 && acc[id].code.push(code)
  //acc[id].subRows.push(curr)  uncomment this when using
    Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    acc[id][k] = acc[id][k] || 0
    if (v!=='')acc[id][k]+=v
  })
  
  return acc
},{}))
    console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What if the keys are dynamic, givenData can have any keys but here its completely static, based on the value we can decide whether its string, date or number

Comment: in givenData we have different keys right based on keys only ur seggregating it, 
const { id, code, accountNo, debtDate, debtAmt, totalPaid, principalDue, principalPaid, interestDue, interestPaid, penaltyDue, penaltyPaid } = curr;
now if another json comes with different set of keys, this wont work right
note: id: will always be there

Comment: @VishnuShenoy If you have other requirements that you did not include in the question, ask a new question and remember to include all requirements, expectations, etc. in the new question.

Comment: @VishnuShenoy i changed a bit now the numeric fields are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You could take arrays for collection and aggregation of other data.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 'ABC001', code: 'AL', accountNo: '57808', debtDate: '2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 20000, totalPaid: 100, principalDue: 5000, principalPaid: 20, interestDue: 1000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 5000, penaltyPaid: 150 }, { id: 'ABC001', code: 'AL', accountNo: '57808', debtDate: '2022-02-01T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 30000, totalPaid: 200, principalDue: 4000, principalPaid: 30, interestDue: 5000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 5000, penaltyPaid: 250 }, { id: 'ABC001', code: 'HL', accountNo: '95783', debtDate: '2022-02-22T03:56:19.517Z', debtAmt: 2000, totalPaid: 300, principalDue: '', principalPaid: 50, interestDue: '', interestPaid: 10, penaltyDue: 4000, penaltyPaid: '' }, { id: 'ABC001', code: 'HL', accountNo: '60092', debtDate: '2022-02-25T00:00:00.000Z', debtAmt: 3000, totalPaid: 400, principalDue: 3000, principalPaid: 80, interestDue: 9000, interestPaid: 20, penaltyDue: 3000, penaltyPaid: 200 }, { id: 'DEF123', code: 'HL', accountNo: '480001', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 2000, totalPaid: '', principalDue: 2000, principalPaid: 10, interestDue: 1000, interestPaid: 50, penaltyDue: 2000, penaltyPaid: 100 }, { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480002', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 3000, totalPaid: '', principalDue: 500, principalPaid: 20, interestDue: 500, interestPaid: 100, penaltyDue: 1000, penaltyPaid: 150 }, { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480003', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 4000, totalPaid: 100, principalDue: 100, principalPaid: 30, interestDue: 200, interestPaid: 200, penaltyDue: 500, penaltyPaid: 250 }, { id: 'DEF123', code: 'DL', accountNo: '480004', debtDate: '2022-03-04T09:51:14.899Z', debtAmt: 5000, totalPaid: 200, principalDue: '', principalPaid: 40, interestDue: 300, interestPaid: 300, penaltyDue: '', penaltyPaid: 300 }, { id: 'DEF123', code: 'AL', accountNo: '480005', debtDate: '2022-03-04T10:52:18.161Z', debtAmt: 6000, totalPaid: 500, principalDue: 50, principalPaid: 60, interestDue: 400, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 100, penaltyPaid: 500 }, { id: 'XYZ001', code: 'PL', accountNo: '878210', debtDate: '2021-09-21T11:38:53.733Z', debtAmt: 500, totalPaid: 600, principalDue: 800, principalPaid: 200, interestDue: 900, interestPaid: 500, penaltyDue: 200, penaltyPaid: 100 }, { id: 'XYZ001', code: 'DL', accountNo: '878211', debtDate: '2021-09-21T11:38:53.733Z', debtAmt: 700, totalPaid: 900, principalDue: 700, principalPaid: 100, interestDue: 300, interestPaid: '', penaltyDue: '', penaltyPaid: '' }],
    collect = ['code', 'accountNo'],
    update = ['debtAmt', 'totalPaid', 'principalDue', 'principalPaid', 'interestDue', 'interestPaid', 'penaltyDue', 'penaltyPaid'],
    updateCollection = (array, v) => array.includes(v) || array.push(v),
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.id] ??= {
            id: o.id,
            ...Object.fromEntries(collect.map(k => [k, []])),
            ...Object.fromEntries(update.map(k => [k, 0])),
            sub: []
        };
        collect.forEach(k => updateCollection(r[o.id][k], o[k]));
        update.forEach(k => r[o.id][k] += o[k] || 0);
        r[o.id].sub.push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```