# Split a JSON file into two and create a two dimensional array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
var data = [
    {
        "re_ID": "15.02",
        "date": "20.01.2016",
        "name": "Opening",
        "booking_ID": "4343",
        "source": "int",
        "meaning": "high",
        "date_booking": "31.05.2018"
    },
    {
        "re_ID": "15.02",
        "date": "20.01.2016",
        "name": "Opening",
        "booking_ID": "333",
        "source": "int",
        "meaning": "high",
        "date_booking": "31.04.2018"
    },
    {
        "re_ID": "15.02",
        "date": "20.01.2016",
        "name": "Opening",
        "booking_ID": "434311",
        "source": "int",
        "meaning": "high",
        "date_booking": "31.01.2018"
    },
    {
        "re_ID": "99.33",
        "date": "11.08.2013",
        "name": "medium",
        "booking_ID": "5411",
        "source": "ext",
        "meaning": "low",
        "date_booking": "11.11.2017"
    }
]
```

I need to transform this into a nested format like in the following example such that I can loop through it with a double loop to get the data from the first dimension while with the second loop I can get the information of the second dimension of it:

The structure I need to have:

```
var data = [
    {
        "re_ID": "15.02",
        "date": "20.01.2016",
        "name": "Opening"
    },
    {
        "booking_ID": "4343",
        "source": "int",
        "meaning": "high",
        "date_booking": "31.05.2018"
    },
    {
        "booking_ID": "333",
        "source": "int",
        "meaning": "high",
        "date_booking": "31.04.2018"
    },
    {
        "booking_ID": "434311",
        "source": "int",
        "meaning": "high",
        "date_booking": "31.01.2018"
    },
    {
        "re_ID": "99.33",
        "date": "11.08.2013",
        "name": "medium"
    },
    {
        "booking_ID": "5411",
        "source": "ext",
        "meaning": "low",
        "date_booking": "11.11.2017"
    }
];
```

How can I build this second JSON from the first JSON

Comment: It's a JSO not JSON... **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject... When it's part of a JS file it's just a Javascript object.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Comment: also, this is an awful way to format your code.. i can't tell what the hell the difference is between the two..

Comment: Your desired structure is impossible. You need a property to hold the array of children. See [Group by array and add field and sub array in main array](//stackoverflow.com/q/34523003) for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by array and add field and sub array in main array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523003/group-by-array-and-add-field-and-sub-array-in-main-array)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: That looks like a significantly different problem.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Now it does. Previously his "desired structure" was completely different.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I saw it. Were the edits supposed to change the op's desired format even if wrong?

Comment: Probably want to ask @Ele why he edited and changed the format.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Only saw the end result.  That edit is significant, probably too significant.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The original version wasn't valid JSON nor a valid JS Object. Ele was possibly guessing at a valid format?

Comment: @JasonCust that's why we have comments; to clarify. That's what my comment was about, and the possible duplicate.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I understand why edit comments exist . I was only venturing a guess for those who want to help. The bigger issue here aside from the OP's apparent misunderstanding of plain ole object syntax is they also haven't posted any code to show where they got stuck. As is, this is just another "do-it-for-me" post.

Comment: I assumed he meant to have some kind of `items: []` wrapped around the subobjects, as yes, the original output format is invalid.

Comment: Oops probably modified in a wrong way.  We should close this question.  The Json wasn’t valid and I tried to “fix” it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I assume the structure you say you want output is not actually what you want, but rather to put the sub objects into an array instead.

I'm also assuming that if the re_ID is the same, then date and name will be the same as well.

You just need to loop through the data array and then group the transformed subobjects by the re_ID. When you're done, transform the collector object back into an array:

(Note that if you need to support IE, you'll need a polyfill for Array.includes())

```
function transformJSON(data) {
    var collector = {};
    var ids = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var reid = data[i].re_ID;
        if (!ids.includes(reid)) {
            collector[reid] = {
                re_ID: reid,
                date: data[i].date,
                name: data[i].name,
                items: []
            };

            ids.push(reid);
        }

        collector[reid].items.push({
            booking_ID: data[i].booking_ID,
            source: data[i].source,
            meaning: data[i].meaning,
            date_booking: data[i].date_booking
        });
    }

    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        output.push(collector[ids[i]]);
    }

    return output;
}
```