# how to group item by id only with item that no parentId and item with parentId keep first item?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

I have a collection like the one below, with the collection, and I want to group it with an id that the item has no parentId. Can help me?

```
let item=[
             {id:'001', name:'A', qty:10,},
             {id:'002', name:'B', qty:5, parentId:'001'},
             {id:'003', name:'C', qty:8, parentId:'001'},
             {id:'001', name:'A', qty:-5,},
             {id:'002', name:'B', qty:-5, parentId:'001'},
             {id:'003', name:'C', qty:-8, parentId:'001'}
             ]
```

I want to group only item no parentId, this is my result.

```
let item=[
             {id:'001', name:'A', qty:5,},                 
             {id:'002', name:'B', qty:5, parentId:'001'},
             {id:'003', name:'C', qty:8, parentId:'001'}
         ]
```

Comment: you could read the code here and learn how to do it, eventhough it's not exactly what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523003/group-by-array-and-add-field-and-sub-array-in-main-array/34523275#34523275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "id": "$id",
                "parentId": "$parentId"
            },
            qtyArray: {
                $push: {
                    "qty": "$qty",
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            count: {
                $cond: [
                    {
                        $not: ["$_id.parentId"]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "qtyTotal": { $sum: "$qtyArray.qty" }
                    },
                    {
                        $arrayElemAt: [ "$qtyArray", 0 ]
                    }
                ]
            }

        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let item = [{
    id: '001',
    name: 'A',
    qty: 10,
  },
  {
    id: '002',
    name: 'B',
    qty: 5,
    parentId: '001'
  },
  {
    id: '003',
    name: 'C',
    qty: 8,
    parentId: '001'
  },
  {
    id: '001',
    name: 'A',
    qty: -5,
  },
  {
    id: '002',
    name: 'B',
    qty: -5,
    parentId: '001'
  },
  {
    id: '003',
    name: 'C',
    qty: -8,
    parentId: '001'
  }
]

item = item.reduce((a, c) => {
  const ex = a.find((v) => v.id === c.id)
  if (ex) {
    if (!ex.parentId) {
      ex.qty += c.qty;
    }
  } else {
    a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(item);
```

Comment: Can you example with aggregate

Comment: What do you mean by aggregate? There's no such method in javascript. @AneatTea

Comment: Looking at the tags, the question is apparently focussed on a mongoDB solution. The OP asked question in a confusing way and added js tag.

Comment: I want item with parentId get only qty only positive number?