# Restructure single JSON into nested array

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
[
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "1", Value: "123"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "2", Value: "3"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "3", Value: "-123"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "4", Value: "-4123"},
...
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "1", Value: "214"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "2", Value: "-41123"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "3", Value: "12344"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "4", Value: "1232"}
]
```

Which I'd like to transform into this:

```
[{ 
  Year : "2019",
    data : [{ 
      Month : "01",
      Value : "123"
    },{
      Month : "02",
      Value : "2223"
    }...
  },{
  Year : "2020",
    data: [{
       Month : "01",
       Value : "214"
    }...
}]
```

Not sure how to do this easily, seems it's beyond me right now.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Many thanks,

Fish

Comment: You want multiple objects as a solution, each for one year or would be a single object that holds all years as key be okay too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by array and add field and sub array in main array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34523003/6320039) (I've issued a close vote for another duplicate, which is less clear than this one)

Comment: Sorry, I did look but couldn't find a similar post.  Solved now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Array.reduce

Here is a working example assuming there are no duplicate entries for the same month/year combination

```js
var testData = [
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "1", Value: "123"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "2", Value: "3"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "3", Value: "-123"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "4", Value: "-4123"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "1", Value: "214"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "2", Value: "-41123"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "3", Value: "12344"},
{Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "4", Value: "1232"}
];

var reducedTestData = testData.reduce((acc, item) => {
 let itemData = {
    Month: item.Month,
    Value: item.Value
  };
 return Object.assign({}, acc, {
   [item.Year]: acc.hasOwnProperty(item.Year) 
     ? Object.assign(
       {}, 
        acc[item.Year], 
        {
         data: acc[item.Year].data.concat(itemData) 
        }
      ) 
      : {data: [itemData]}
  });
}, {});

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = JSON.stringify(reducedTestData, null, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of a solution:

```
const source =  [
    {Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "1", Value: "123"},
    {Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "2", Value: "3"},
    {Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "3", Value: "-123"},
    {Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2019", Month: "4", Value: "-4123"},
    {Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "1", Value: "214"},
    {Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "2", Value: "-41123"},
    {Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "3", Value: "12344"},
    {Id: "1", Id2: "1", Year: "2020", Month: "4", Value: "1232"}
];

const destination = []
const classifiedTokens = [] // will be used to stored already classified tokens

const getNextTokenArray = function(source) {
    let unusedToken = null;
    const nextTokenArray = source.filter(function(element) {
        if (!unusedToken && !classifiedTokens.includes(element["Year"])) {
            unusedToken = element["Year"]
            classifiedTokens.push(unusedToken)
        }
        return unusedToken ? unusedToken === element["Year"] : false;
    });
    return unusedToken ? nextTokenArray : null;
}

const addToDestination = function(tokenArray) {
    if (tokenArray.length === 0) return
    let res = {
        Year : tokenArray[0]["Year"],
        data : []
    }
    tokenArray.forEach((element) => {
        res.data.push({
            Month: element.Month,
            Value: element.Value
        })
    })
    destination.push(res);
}

let nextTokenArray = getNextTokenArray(source);
while (nextTokenArray) {
    addToDestination(nextTokenArray)
    nextTokenArray = getNextTokenArray(source)
}

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = JSON.stringify(destination, null, 2);
```

you can try it directly in the following fidle: https://jsfiddle.net/zgj0fcq9/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Reduce is often used to take an array and turn it into a single value, e.g. summing items in an array:

```
let vs = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(vs.reduce(function(accumulator, value){ return accumulator + value; }, 0));
```

The second parameter in reduce is the default (or starting) value (in the above that's `0`).

So to reduce your array of objects into your array of nested objects, you'll need to check your accumulator to see if the year already exists in the outer array:

```
let year = accumulator.find(item => item.Year === value.Year);
```

If `year` is undefined then you'll need to create a new object with the current year, and give it a `data` property that's an array with one item that is an object with the `Month` and `Value` properties set.

```
let newYear = { Year: value.Year, data: [{ Month: value.Month, Value: value.Value}]}
```

Then add that to the accumulator (e.g. with `push`).

If the year does exist in the accumulator then you'll need to add a new object to the data property:

```
year.data.push({Month: value.Month, Value: value.Value});
```

Then you're done.