# Show title for each group that is grouped by value from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I am receiving data as an array of objects in JS. Each object has a value `month` and I want to show data with groups according to month. Example:

```
data: [
{id: 0001,month:2,desc:'objectone'},
{id: 0001,month:4,desc:'objecttwo'},
{id: 0001,month:4,desc:'objectthree'},
{id: 0001,month:4,desc:'objectfour'},
{id: 0001,month:5,desc:'objectfive'},
{id: 0001,month:5,desc:'objectsix'}
]
```

Now I want to show it like this:

```
<h1>Month {month}</h1>
<p>{desc}</p>
```

Month 2
objectone

Month 4
objecttwoo
objectthree
objectfour

Month 5
objectfive
objectsix

I've used `reduce` to group it by the value but still having issue in mapping it to show as described above.
After reduce I get one object that contains array of objects:

```
data: {
1:(1) [{...}],
2:(3) [{...}],
3:(2) [{...}]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So, you already have the processed data and you just want to represent it in the given html format?

Comment: I think you are not providing data received from the API. If the data is the array you shared then I think its already grouped.

Comment: use a map on Object.keys or Objject.entries of reduced data

Comment: I think you can look at this post (not all answare but you have a logical process) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72717426/best-way-to-split-a-array-for-a-specific-condition/72717684#72717684

Comment: Thanks @JessyViotti, it really helped. Basically I already got the values that I need as object keys for the group it was just not evident since it started from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've grouped the data you can loop through it using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then inside the loop create the heading and the para for every month.

```js
const data = [
  { id: "0001", month: 2, desc: "objectone" },
  { id: "0001", month: 4, desc: "objecttwo" },
  { id: "0001", month: 4, desc: "objectthree" },
  { id: "0001", month: 4, desc: "objectfour" },
  { id: "0001", month: 5, desc: "objectfive" },
  { id: "0001", month: 5, desc: "objectsix" },
];

const groups = data.reduce((r, d) => ((r[d.month] ??= []).push(d.desc), r), {});

Object.entries(groups).forEach(([mon, desc]) => {
  const h2 = document.createElement("h2");
  h2.textContent = `Month ${mon}`;
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = desc.join(" ");
  document.body.appendChild(h2);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned in the comment I got the values as object keys for each group as a value. This works as I described, my presentation logic will be a bit different since I didn't want to over complicate but to grasp the logical approach to the problem.